# Sencha Cmd build - Failed creating background process

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs5

I'm trying to build extjs5 application with Cmd v5.0.0.160.

I have ruby2.0 installed and sencha cmd on my PATH var.

Here is the error that I get when running `sencha app build`:

```
...
[INF] Capturing theme image
[ERR] 
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
[ERR]   at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeRe
[ERR] verseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
[ERR] 
[ERR] Total time: 9 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/local/dev/PROJECTS2/loc-ext/loc-ext/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/local/dev/PROJECTS2/loc-ext/loc-ext/.sencha/app/slice-impl.xml:239: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/local/dev/PROJECTS2/loc-ext/loc-ext/.sencha/app/slice-impl.xml:240: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/local/dev/PROJECTS2/loc-ext/loc-ext/.sencha/app/slice-impl.xml:111: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
```

The application is working OK in development mode (sencha app watch).

Since it looks like it's about themes, I'm not using custom theme but ext-theme-neptune.

Does anybody have a clue what is it about? 
I will appreciate any idea!

**Solution:**

The debug mode showed that the problem was in missing directory `Cmd/5.0.0.160/bin/linux-x64`. However there was `Cmd/5.0.0.160/bin/linux` dir, therefor soft-linking `linux` to `linux-x64` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a really annoying bug in Sencha CMD 5 - they swallow the output of any processes they launch.

Or, more accurately, they route the output to the debug logs. So you can see what's going on if you turn debug logging on. Try `sencha -d app build` - just be prepared to trawl through a lot of output.

Comment: Ah, shame on me for not checking debug log. Apparently there were a dir missing `Cmd/5.0.0.160/bin/linux-x64`. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Same issues with EXT5.0 + EXT CMD Vers. 5.1.2.52

(causing EXT CMD cannot start RUBY)

It hangs with Error:

```
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
```

My Solution on Windows (Here Win7, 64Bit):

1) install Ruby (in my Case 1.9.3)

**2) Set %PATH% in System Settings to Ruby´s EXE. (in my case c:\ruby193\bin)**

3) Restart CMD window

4) Try again

That solves my problem.

Answer (score 8):

Sencha cmd requires ruby which might be a problem to why it can't create a (ruby) background builder of some sort.

Comment: Yes, this is the reason in my case as well. I am using Ubuntu. After I installed Ruby in Ubuntu Software Center, the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux: Please ensure that the missing libs are installed (ruby, rubygems, freetype, fontconfig)

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue exists with version `7.5.1`, which is resulting in the same error message; when running `sencha -d upgrade` it downloads the ZIP, but then it cannot locate the shell script within the `/tmp` directory. So I tried to manually download it. The version number contained isn't `7.5.1`, but it's actually `7.5.1.20` ...which means the installer is just broken:

```
cd ./Downloads
wget http://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/7.5.1/no-jre/SenchaCmd-7.5.1-linux-amd64.sh.zip
unzip SenchaCmd-7.5.1-linux-amd64.sh.zip
./SenchaCmd-7.5.1.20-linux-amd64.sh

Starting Installer ...
```